# I have a problem in changing Java to pseudo code

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

Given two unsorted arrays of distinct elements, the task is to find all pairs from both arrays whose sum is equal to x.
Examples:

```
    Input :  arr1[] = {-1, -2, 4, -6, 5, 7}
             arr2[] = {6, 3, 4, 0}  
             x = 8
    Output : 4 4
             5 3
    
    Input : arr1[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7} 
            arr2[] = {5, 6, 3, 4, 8}  
            x = 9
    Output : 1 8
             4 5
             5 4
```

An Efficient solution of this problem is to hashing. We store all first array elements in hash table. For elements of second array, we subtract every element from x and check the result in hash table. If result is present, we print the element and key in hash (which is an element of first array).
Here is the code:

```
    // JAVA Code for Given two unsorted arrays,  
    // find all pairs whose sum is x 
    import java.util.*; 
      
    class GFG { 
      
         // Function to find all pairs in both arrays 
        // whose sum is equal to given value x 
        public static void findPairs(int arr1[], int arr2[], 
                                     int n, int m, int x) 
        { 
            // Insert all elements of first array in a hash 
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> s = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
              
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) 
                s.put(arr1[i], 0); 
           
            // Subtract sum from second array elements one 
            // by one and check it's present in array first 
            // or not 
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++) 
                if (s.containsKey(x - arr2[j])) 
                    System.out.println(x - arr2[j] + " " + arr2[j]);              
        } 
          
        /* Driver program to test above function */
        public static void main(String[] args)  
        { 
            int arr1[] = {1, 0, -4, 7, 6, 4}; 
            int arr2[] = {0 ,2, 4, -3, 2, 1}; 
            int x = 8; 
              
            findPairs(arr1, arr2, arr1.length, arr2.length, x); 
           
        } 
      }
```

The question I want to ask is: what is the time complexity of this code? How can I write the pseudo code of this Java code?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your algorithm must iterate through all elements in the second array to find a solution, You have a worst case(or all cases for that matter) of n where n is the length of the second array. Therefore you have a O(n) algorithm.

With regard to writing pseudo-code:

You have mostly already done this in your description of the algorithm, however it may be more constructive to write a formal list of steps in the algorithm. In general you can accomplish this by writing an abstract description of each step of the algorithm that is independent of any programming language.

For example, instead of writing `for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++)` which is language specific - you might instead write "Iterate through all elements in arr2".